# R Integer Overflow

Tags: programming-languages

I have a quick question. I have a huge database and I am try to sum all the elements in a column of my data base but there are over 100,000 values and I consequently, get integer overflow (returns NA). How do I get around this in R?

Comment: "How do I get around this in R?"  Do you mean by using reals ?  What is the meaning of your title? Is it the case that your data base contains integers, but you are willing to convert to reals?

Comment: Questions about R or how to implement something in R are off-topic: questions about how to use programming languages or write code in a particular language are off-topic for CS.SE (but might be on-topic for Cross Validated or StackOverflow).

Comment: What babou is suggesting is that you first convert the data in that column to floating point numbers, and then sum them. This is probably the easiest way out.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Big Integers!

Answer (score 1):

From their documentation on `help(integer)`:

`Note that current implementations of R use 32-bit integers for integer vectors, so the range of representable integers is restricted to about +/-2*10^9: doubles can hold much larger integers exactly.`

So if you are already using `numeric` or `double`, I believe there is no way around it. It would be very helpful though if you present an example of your data or a clarification of your question.

: )

Answer (score 1):

Use the [gmp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html) package. This provides arbitrary precision integers (BigInts).